# Calling spark-submit in a shell script is masking the exit code for spark-submit

Tags: bash, shell, apache-spark, exit-code, spark-submit

I'm calling spark-submit from inside of a shell script, like so:

```
spark-submit --class my.App --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster ./Spark_job.jar
```

Even when the job fails and this the last command in the script,the output of `echo $?` is 0

When I execute the same spark-submit command directly on the shell, the output of `$?` is non-zero and appropriately describing the error that was encountered

In my shell script I've tried storing the output of the spark-submit, like so:

```
exit_code=`spark-submit --class my.App --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster ./Spark_job.jar`
```

But it remains empty.

Directly calling `echo $?` after the spark-submit inside the shell script results in 0.

What I can do capture the exit code when calling spark-submit from inside a shell script?

PS- Just as a sanity test i ran a program "lss" at the end of my script which does not exists and for that, the exit codes were rightly 127 and easily captured, so it confirmed my suspicion that the problem lies with spark submit.

Comment: Well the backquotes won't help, that captures stdout, not exit code.

Comment: From what you describe you aren't doing anything wrong, but you must be doing something wrong. You could try putting "exit $?" after every call to spark

Comment: _Directly calling echo $? after the spark-submit inside the shell script results in 0._  This means that `spark-submit` simply returns exit code 0. What else would you like to see? If you want to have a different exit code under certain conditions, please file a change-request to the developers of spark-submit. An alternative would be to analyze the stdout and/or stderr of spark-submit to get more information on what has been done.

Comment: @user1934428 I'm not able to understand why the exit code correctly depends on the outcome of spark-submit when i call it directly on my shell but when I use it inside my script it is always 0 even if there is an error.

Comment: You're doing something in your script that you haven't told us about yet. Create and post a **minimal** complete script that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Gestalt : I don't know `spark-submit`, but there MUST be a difference. I suggest that you post two screenshots (one showing calling it directly in your shell, and one showing calling it from the script (don't for get to turn on `set -x` inside your script before you do your submit)), which prove your point that you see two different exit codes.

Comment: You guys were right,it was a mistake at my end. There were around 50 commented commands between the spark-submit and the exit command and someone had uncommented an echo on #43 which was causing the exit code to reflect the status of the echo.